# Describe terminated ec2 instances, or access spot instance history via CLI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to get the launch and termination times of instances in a spot fleet request. This data is visible in the *new* spot requests console under the "History" tab when a spot request is selected. `aws ec2 describe-instances` only lists recently terminated instances (in accordance with the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)).

Short of saving my browser cookies and making requests to the URL used by the console (`https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2sp/services/fleet/<sfr-id>/history`), is there a CLI command that will expose this data?

Answer (score 1):

The cli request you are looking for is the newly added `describe-spot-fleet-request-history` 
This is still under the `aws ec2` command chain. There have been several added that could be useful.

`describe-spot-fleet-instances
describe-spot-fleet-request-history
describe-spot-fleet-requests`